# Selenium get comments from posts

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I’m trying to retrieve text from a webpage marked as a SPAN within a CLASS. I’ve tried this with Xpath, but this won’t work because the tag is encountered multiple times. I use Jupyter Notebook to write the program.

Here is an example from Instagram:

```
<div class="C4VMK">
<a class="FPmhX notranslate TlrDj" title="henkbrinkman1994" 
href="/henkbrinkman1994/">henkbrinkman1994</a>
<span>Awesome!</span>
</div>
```

In this case i want to get the text 'Awesome!' in the SPAN tag.
How can I do this in Selenium Python?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5feDV.png)

Comment: Please include the xpath that you are trying to use.

Comment: This is the Xpath from Instagram

//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/span

This is only the Xpath of one comment. So as soon as I put this in a for loop, it only gets the comment that the Xpath refers to while I want to collect all the comments under a post.

Comment: which tag is used multiple times?  Also, it would be helpful to see more of the outer HTML.  Is this basically a list of items, and you're trying to get all of the different text from that span element?  something else?

Comment: I have added a picture of the HTML to my post, hopefully it will make things clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an Instagram account, nor do I have permission to use automation to collect information from their site (see their terms of service), so I can't really test this.  The idea is that you would use find_element_by_xpath() to find the particular post (or find_elements_by_xpath() to get all of them).

```
my_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/xpath/to/a/post')
```

Then for each post use the same method to get the list of comments:

```
post_comments = my_post.find_elements_by_xpath('./relative/xpath/to/comments')
```

You can then loop through the objects in post_comments to get the text.

```
for post in post_comments:
    print post.text
```

[there are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but this will get you started]

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of such a loop?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a loop to print the text

Answer (score 0):

The desired element looks to be a dynamic element so to get the comment with text as **Awesome!** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `XPATH#1`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'notranslate') and contains(.,'henkbrinkman1994')]//following::span[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- `XPATH#2`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'notranslate') and @title='henkbrinkman1994']//following::span[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternative locator strategy because its not 100% surety that your xpath will work every time.

Use below css Selector

```
div[class='C4VMK'] span
```

OR

```
.C4VMK span
```

Make sure your element has been loaded and visible enough if not then try different  ExplicitWait conditions to make them work.

Comment: I already had that solution in my mind, but it always takes the first reaction and then shows it as often as there are reactions

Comment: Then i guess you have to loop through all your actions

Comment: the class here looks like it was generated, which suggests that it will not be the same every time that you run your test.  That will make this approach brittle.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware, Yep its just an example and that we have to observe. we can make it unique by taking some parent element as well which is fix